# Phaser - Repeat three background

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have 3 background images.

```
 game.load.image('bg1', 'https://www.joshmorony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-back.png');
 game.load.image('bg2', 'https://www.joshmorony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-mid1.png');
 game.load.image('bg3', 'https://www.joshmorony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-mid2.png');
```

I try to repeat 3 nearby image by Horizontal forever

like `..|bg1|bg2|bg3|bg1|...`

And a player can moving on that.

```
game.load.image('player', 'http://examples.phaser.io/_site/images/prize-button.png');
```

I try to use tileSprite but it only in one background repeat
How to do that?

I made a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/30t5e4eg/

Answer (score 0):

You can join the 3 images in a BitmapData (copy) and then use a tileSprite. The problem is that the images are disproportionate both in size and color. So I personally think it is easier to use a single image. I found a very good example on the internet of the user **[@lewster32](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/8356-simple-background-image-question/#comment-49891)**:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

var tilesprite,
    cameraPosition,
    lerp,
    cursors, 
    player;

function preload() {
    game.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    game.load.image('player', 'http://examples.phaser.io/_site/images/prize-button.png');
    game.load.image('bg1', 'https://www.joshmorony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/mountains-back.png');
}

function create() {
    cameraPosition = new Phaser.Point(0, 0);
    lerp = 0.1;
    //A tileSprite is added and fixed to the camera
    tilesprite = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, game.width, game.height, 'bg1');
    tilesprite.fixedToCamera = true;
    tilesprite.tileScale.set(0.9);

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    player = game.add.sprite((game.width / 2), (game.height / 2), 'player');
    player.scale.setTo(0.8);

    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, game.width * 5, game.height);
    cameraPosition.setTo(player.x, player.y);
}

function update() {
    if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT))
    {
        player.x -= 4;
    }
    else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT))
    {
        player.x += 4;
    }
    else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP))
    {
        player.y -= 4;
    }
    else if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN))
    {
        player.y += 4;
    }
    //This prevents the camera from moving violently or quickly, takes the variable lerp, if its value is very low the movement will be smoother
    cameraPosition.x += (player.x - cameraPosition.x) * lerp;
    cameraPosition.y += (player.y - cameraPosition.y) * lerp;
    //Move the camera to the new point
    game.camera.focusOnXY(cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y);
    //This is optional, in this case the background is repeated every time
    tilesprite.tilePosition.x += 5;
    //tilesprite.tilePosition.set(game.camera.x * -1, game.camera.y * -1);
}
```

I still do not know what type of mobility you are looking for so I only share the code so that I can implement it in your project.

Comment: I think we will not use tileSprite and loop background by code when player moving